# How to show 3d Pie chart in Tableau

Tags: 3d, pie-chart, tableau-api

Is it possible to create 3D pie-Chart in Tableau. If yes, like to see the process. or is their any alternative to Show 3D pie-chart in tableau.

Comment: It would be better if it were not possible to create a 3D pie chart in any visualization tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3D pie charts are generally considered as sub-optimal in the data visualisation world and I would never advise anyone to use a 3D pie chart.

Here are some links that talk about this:

- http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf
- http://blog.visual.ly/2ds-company-3ds-a-crowd/
- http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6

That said, if you really really need to make a 3D pie chart in Tableau, then you can hack your way to one: http://gravyanecdote.com/andy-cotgreave/3d-pie-charts-in-tableau/ but be warned, most of the data visualisation world will rage against it.